# How to show formated date in input form in JSP using JSTL tags & converting Java code to JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I have two issues,one is why can't i show the formatedDate using ${formatedDate} in the forms.
Second is how can I convert the java code to format date in JSTL? Is there a reference or something where I could get to translate java code into JSTL?

```
                    <% 
                        LocalDate date = workorder.getCreationDate();
                        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
                        String formatedDate = date.format(formatter);
                        out.println(formatedDate);                  
                    
                    %>
                    <c:out value="${formatedDate }"></c:out> // this shows
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="workorderDate" value=${formatedDate }>   // this doesn't show
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="workorderDate" value="${formatedDate }"> // this doesn't show
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="workorderDate" value=<%=formatedDate%>>  // this one shows
```

Comment: Not sure why this has been closed given that the related question has nothing to do with this. But there is a third party library you can use to format java.time.* classes in jsp/jstl: https://github.com/sargue/java-time-jsptags

Comment: Thanks, but what I am looking for is clarification on why EL tag is not being processed.

Comment: @Ali I can't put answer, but in my test, the `<c:out>` part doesn't show on the page.  Only the `out.println`and the `<%=formatedDate%>` do. This is logical as the EL `${}` construct can only see the content of the PageContext, and not the local variable `formatedDate`.